# Create a custom main menu for each `NSViewController` Swift

Tags: swift, nsviewcontroller

I have an app with many ViewControllers and I need to have custom main menu for each of them (e.g. in one I need to have such buttons as "play" or "pause" and in another - "change background" or "change speed". Is there any way to do that in swift?